# Creating multiple tags and keeping them in a list for display

Tags: java, swing, list, append, jtextfield

just as we select `tags` before posting a question on stack overflow, I wanted to do something similar when registering a contact into database. In the form, there is a JTextField  `txtTags` which asks for a word to best describe a contact. i.e. Contact John Smith is best described by `java`. java becomes the tag.

My confusion lies in in multiple tags being created for a contact where I need to display a list of tags before adding to database. It would be great just like stackoverflow post questions tags part allows to remove the tag if you make a mistake.

[image]

So just below the text field, I would like to display all the tags.

1. Please can you show me how to go about with the logic.
2. I am using java reflector field, so DTOs and DAOs. In the DTO, how would the tag field setter and getter logic work, I think something to do with list.

I would appreciate a sample to code to demonstrate the ideas. arraylist, list, collections anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get text from the textfield. Split it to have array of tag names (in fact String[]). For each tag name in the array you should check your list of existing tags and figure out whether there is a tag for each tag name.
For the found ones you can show a popup or something... or throw an error when some tag is not found.

Comment: +1 aaach now I understood, but then you forgot to mentioned some AutoComplete for this JTextField

Comment: autocomplete is not required for now. can you show me how to do this, I am confused at the point of for loop

Comment: @MooHa how you keep list of existing tags?

Comment: that's beyond my requirement at this stage. priority really is create links as they are added and displayed. so allow the removing of such created tags.

Answer (score 1):

1. create [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) contains [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) (maybe not requied, but then you have to restrict number of visible rows, maybe bad idea, maybe not)
2. have to decide about numbers of column, (2- 4 columns???), maybe to remove `showHorizontalLines`, `showVerticalLines`, then you'll the same autocomplete as you wanted
3. put there (to the `JDialog`) [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and to use [Filtering in JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), everything is encoded in the example `JTable`  from tutorial [TableFilterDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java)